# Excel indirect: formula is too long

Tags: excel-formula, array-formulas

I have this code to get row number from 5 to 400.

```
 ROW(INDIRECT("5:400"))
```

When I highlighted the whole thing and hit F9, I got an array ranging from 5 to 400. However, when I highlighted "INDIRECT("5:400")" and hit F9 I got an error message saying "Formula is too long..."

I wonder why it's so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presume you have nothing entered in Row `5`, the following formulas will try to return 16,384 units of `0` separated by comma sign `,` for Row `5` in a single formula when you press <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
=5:5 or =INDIRECT("5:5")
```

The maximum characters can be shown by a single formula is `8192` as shown below so it explained why excel is unable to return the value behind your `INDIRECT` formula, which is trying to return 16,384 x 396 times of of zero plus comma `0,` (presume they are all empty) in a single formula.

[image]

FYI `16,384` is the maximum columns of an excel worksheet. See [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).